# Find Eclipse Version from Command prompt(cmd)

Tags: eclipse, cmd, eclipse-rcp

I'm doing Eclipse plugin development, and i need to find the version of the Eclipse IDE I have currently installed. In stead of opening the IDE, is there any cmd commands that I can execute to find the same?
Something like-

> eclipse.exe --version

if that is possible?

Answer (score 1):

Well in Windows I can do:

```
C:\dev\eclipse>type .eclipseproduct
name=Eclipse Platform
id=org.eclipse.platform
version=4.4.2
```

Or find the BuildID in `config.ini` under `configuration` folder:

```
C:\dev\eclipse\configuration>type config.ini | findstr /i BuildID
eclipse.buildId=4.4.2.M20150204-1700
```

(similar can be done in linux/unix with `cat` and `grep` of course.)

---

### Blank Build ID/Version

Why your build id is blank is strange, could you upload a screenshot from your help -> about window.

Could you share your `eclipse.ini` and please refer to the installation bundle that has been used.

Eclipse version/build is based on the product (see your eclipse.ini, **org.eclipse.epp.***)

In later versions (for example if using) JEE EPP there should be a file called `about.mappings` file, e.g. 
`C:\dev\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.epp.package.jee_4.6.2.20161208-0625\about.mappings`

```
# about.mappings
# contains fill-ins for about.properties
# java.io.Properties file (ISO 8859-1 with "\" escapes)
# This file does not need to be translated.

0=MrSimpleMind-Null
1=Neon.2 Release (4.6.2)
```

I edited the file like shown above and the result below in screenshot:
[image]

But this is not the solution of the problem, I would like to know why your values are blank. Do you have conflict in your EPP, try to update your eclipse environment (?)

Comment: Hi, so the eclipse build that my company rolls out doesn't have the eclipse version under the "About" tab under "Help". Granted I can get the version number of from .eclipseproduct, any idea what files I have to edit to add the Version number under "help">"About" ?

Comment: The Build Id can be find in `config.ini` which is in the `configuration` folder. But I doubt it is the same info that puts into the help->about, I guess that is fetched from the product or launcher maybe. So it is deeper in the jars/code/manifests somewhere. (I will try to check the sourcecode when I have more time) ;)

Comment: Can importing org.eclipse.core.resource.* help? Can't find good documentation on this.

Comment: Hey, thanks for adding the information, I actually wrote a code which will append the value from .eclipse to .mappings file and it worked. But it turns out that this is a crude way and what they need is an API call to figure out that information in stead. Can I use any org.eclipse APIs to retrieve that info while running a Java program on Eclipse?